# Rancher Desktop macOS: Store images, containers and volumes in custom path

Tags: docker, rancher, rancher-desktop

Is it possible in Rancher Desktop on macOS to specify the path, where all data (containers, images, volumes) are stored?

As far as I know Rancher Desktop creates (like Docker Desktop) a VM in which all these data is stored, so is it possible to set the path where the VM is created manually?